# Replace a string, in some conditions, in a file

Tags: string, windows, batch-file, replace, find

I have file whose format like this:

```
tcpport 1500
webports 1500,1500
tcpclientport 1500
```

I want to replace `1500` by `1510`, only
when I find the string `webports`.

I found many scripts on searching and replacing strings, but they replace all the occurrences of a string by another string. That's not what I want.

How can I do that in a Windows batch file?

Comment: Would the scripts that you found work if you replaced `webports 1500` with `webports 1510` instead of just trying to replace the number by itself?

Comment: Your task and question is unclear! Which `1500` do you want to replace? All instances within the file, if that file includes the string `webports`? All instances of `1500` on any line which contains the string `webports`? The first instance of `1500` on any line which contains the string `webports`? The second instance of `1500` on any line which contains the string `webports`? or something else completely.

Comment: Also, is your file, by any chance, `%ProgramFiles‰\Tivoli\TSM\baclient\dsm.opt`, and if so, why did you not tell us that information. The more information you provide, especially when you have shown absolutely no effort at attempting the task yourself, the more chance you have in someone at least pointing you to something which may help. Please try to use this site as a resource for fixing a specific issue with your submitted code, not somewhere for free programming hire.

Comment: Hi Compo, you are right. I want to change the string 1500 by 1510 in the dsm.opt file when the first word on the line is TCPPORT ( whatever the case of letters) . I am still looking for a solution.

Comment: That is not what you asked though, is it? So now you've completely changed your question, or introduced another requirement along side the original. Also, if you want me to know that you've commented, you need to precede my account name with `@`. Please use the [edit] button, and formulate an on topic and fully understandable question, so that we can all reproduce the scenario. Currently you've not done that. Please also take the site [tour] and read through the [ask] pages.

Answer (score 0):

```
Here is an answer

================================
@::-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
@:: --- Fonction substitute_str
@::-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
:substitute_str

@echo off
setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

set "oldstring=%1"   rem string to replace
set "newstring=%2"   rem replacing string
set "textFile=%3"    rem file where replacement will take place
set "texttosearch=%4" rem string to be present in the line so that replacement could take place.

set "FICWORK=C:\temp\EvoSvgWin.wrk"
set "FICTEMP=C:\temp\EvoSvgWin.out"

for /f "delims=" %%i in ('type %textFile% ^& break ^> %textFile% ') do (

    set "line=%%i"
    type NUL > %FICTEMP%
    echo(!line! > %FICWORK%
    
    type "%FICWORK%" | findstr /I "%texttosearch%"  > %FICTEMP%
    for %%S in ("%FICTEMP%") do ( @set "size=%%~zS" )
    if NOT !size! EQU 0 (       
            echo(!line:%oldstring%=%newstring%! >> %textFile% 
    ) else (
            echo(!line! >> %textFile%
    )
        
    endlocal

)
del %FICTEMP% %FICWORK%

EXIT /B 0
==========================================================================
NB : >> %textFile%  is necessary because the function can be called many times with the same file so that all replacements could take place in the same.
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).